# What is the preposition category of "along"?

Tags: prepositions

Most place prepositions have an instance for each of the informal preposition categories - I'll refer to them as *active* and *passive*, since I'm not familiar with the actual terms.  I'm using *active* here to refer to prepositions which signify movement, and *passive* to refer to those which signify a state of staying.  For example: the active *into* and the passive *in*, the active *up* and the passive *above/upon*.

Sentences:

> I am *going* **into** the house.
>
> He *is* **in** the house.

It is obvious from these examples that the two forms of the "in" preposition have different meanings - one active and one passive.

You can do the same for every place preposition, though some, like *between*, are the same word when either active or passive.  So there is a *between* meaning something *is* between, and a *between* meaning something *is going* between.

Sentences:

> I am *going* **between** the two big trees.
>
> He *is* **between** the house and the stable.

It is obvious that in both cases the preposition remains the same, though one is active and one passive.

Basically, to find the two forms, you pick a place preposition (say *into*), determine whether it refers to *going* or just to *being* ("He is **going** into the house" - sounds right; "He **is** into the house" - sounds terrible; so "into" is *active*), then search for the form you didn't pick (*passive*, so what sounds right with "He **is** [prep] the house"? - *in* - "He is *in* the house" sounds right, so *in* is the passive form of into), and there you have your two forms (*into* - active; *in* - passive).

What I'm trying to figure out is where *along* fits in.  Is it active, and if so, what is a passive counterpart?

Comment: gotcha. redundant comments deleted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fear your categorization is based on unsound foundations, but let's just look at *along*:

> The signs were on buildings **along** Main Street.

Passive.

> He traveled **along** roads that were long and painted purple.

Active.

Assuming that I correctly understand how you're categorizing prepositions, then it's a preposition that can be in either state.

Comment: @waiwai In curiosity: why are my foundations unsound?

Comment: @drm65 I'm not certain that categorization is incorrect, but it's just a gut feeling I have.

Comment: So, assuming this *active/passive* distinction is meaningful in the first place, **along** works the same as **between**?

Comment: @FumbleFingers That was the conclusion I drew, yes.

Comment: Your categorisation is fine, but the terms you have chosen are unconventional and will not be understood unless you explain them. The distinction is usually expressed as one of "position" or "motion", and is well known: those European languages which still have noun cases usually use the accusative for motion and another case for position.

Answer (score 1):

Along is a preposition of **place and direction**. Active and passive might work for understanding and visualizing the word but not as standard grammar categories for prepositions.

Answer (score 0):

I think "with" is what you're looking for. "To get along with" somebody is to maintain a tolerant if not friendly relationship with them.